# Not able to add custom Header text in WebApi GET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a fully working Visual Studio WebApi solution and I'm trying now to add some custom header information in the return response header but on the client side I am able to receive only the standard ones like the following ones:

[image]

Here the code of the GetCustomer WebApi:

```
    public class CustomerController : ApiController
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult<List<Models.Customer>> GetCustomers()
        {

            EntityMapper<DataAccessLayer.Customer, Models.Customer> mapObj = new EntityMapper<DataAccessLayer.Customer, Models.Customer>();
            List<DataAccessLayer.Customer> custList = DAL.GetAllCustomers();
            List<Models.Customer> customers = new List<Models.Customer>();

            foreach (var item in custList)
            {
                customers.Add(mapObj.Translate(item));
            }

            // Setting Header  
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("Some-Header", "Some-Text"));


            // Returning List of Customers Collections  
            return Json<List<Models.Customer>>(customers);
        }
```

As a result the **HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("Some-Header", "Some-Text"));** does not generate error but is completely ignnored.

Any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found myself the issue.
Because of the CORS I had to explicit instruct the response to expose custom Headers.

Adding:

HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Some-Header");

solved the issue!